# Using Promise.allSettled to stress test JSON API. Why do rejections increase on subsequent requests?

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

Good morning. I came up with the following code to stress test a simple JSON API.

```
/*
  ACME HTTP Stress Tester 5000
*/
let promises: Promise<any>[] = [];
let fulfilled: number = 0;
let rejected: number = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 3000; ++i) {
  // push fetch into array of promises
  promises.push(fetch('http://localhost:80/api/v1/index.json'));
}

// Execute test in Parallel
await Promise.allSettled(promises).then((results) => {

  results.forEach((result) => {
    if(result.status == 'fulfilled') fulfilled++;
    if(result.status == 'rejected') rejected++;
  });

  console.log(`
Total Requests:  ${results.length}
Total Fulfilled: ${fulfilled}
Total Rejected:  ${rejected}`);

});
```

Looking at the output you can see it starts great then begins to degrade in subsequent requests. Am I hitting some sort of network connection pool limit or am I doing it wrong?

```
C:\Users\nexlevel\.deno\bin>deno run --allow-all stress.ts

Total Requests:  3000
Total Fulfilled: 3000
Total Rejected:  0

C:\Users\nexlevel\.deno\bin>deno run --allow-all stress.ts

Total Requests:  3000
Total Fulfilled: 3000
Total Rejected:  0

C:\Users\nexlevel\.deno\bin>deno run --allow-all stress.ts

Total Requests:  3000
Total Fulfilled: 3000
Total Rejected:  0

C:\Users\nexlevel\.deno\bin>deno run --allow-all stress.ts

Total Requests:  3000
Total Fulfilled: 2012
Total Rejected:  988

C:\Users\nexlevel\.deno\bin>deno run --allow-all stress.ts

Total Requests:  3000
Total Fulfilled: 1662
Total Rejected:  1338

C:\Users\nexlevel\.deno\bin>deno run --allow-all stress.ts

Total Requests:  3000
Total Fulfilled: 794
Total Rejected:  2206

C:\Users\nexlevel\.deno\bin>deno run --allow-all stress.ts

Total Requests:  3000
Total Fulfilled: 367
Total Rejected:  2633

C:\Users\nexlevel\.deno\bin>deno run --allow-all stress.ts

Total Requests:  3000
Total Fulfilled: 242
Total Rejected:  2758
```

Ironically, if I just wait 10 seconds and run it again, it will once again fulfill all 3000 parallel requests.

The `Promise.allSettled` error:

```
TypeError: error sending request for url (http://localhost/api/v1/index.json): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (os error 10048)
    at deno:core/01_core.js:106:46
    at unwrapOpResult (deno:core/01_core.js:126:13)
    at async mainFetch (deno:ext/fetch/26_fetch.js:265:14)
```

Comment: Well, what is the server doing? Is it busy sending responses to sockets that are already closed?

Comment: That said, maybe you'll want to not reinvent the wheel and just use e.g. https://github.com/fcsonline/drill ?

Comment: AKX, the server is saying `Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.`. I have also posted this question in Deno's Discord chat and they found it... interesting initially describing it as a potential bug worth looking into.

Comment: Drill looks pretty awesome. Currently reading it.